# Каким образом можно в массиве подсчитать количество номеров ([1] параметр)?

Tags: python, массивы, файлы

```
filename = input('Enter name of file: ')
file = open(filename, 'r')
mass = []
mass1 = []

mass = file.readlines()
for i in mass:
     mass1.append(i.strip().split(','))

for i in mass1:
      if(int(i[1])<195000):
         print(len(int[1]) + 'обслуживает оператор')
file.close()
```

Файл который считывает прога:

```
Franklin,195130,Avenu,312,20

Tramp,193484,Avenu,210,20

Linkoln,195347,Avenu,255,20

Eltsin,193584,Bosforska,450,30

Kirov,195893,Bosforska,430,30

Andropov,195983,Bosforska,420,30

Brezhnev,193849,Lenina,345,40

Stalin,195738,Lenina,349,40

Lenin,193948,Lenina,330,40
```

Как можно подсчитать отдельно номера которые начинаются на `193***` и на `195***` отдельно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если просто посчитать количество:

```
import math

filename = input('Enter name of file: ')
file = open(filename, 'r')
mass = file.readlines()
file.close() 
m193 = 0
m195 = 0

for i in mass:
    row = i.strip().split(',')

    if len(row) > 1:
        n = math.floor(int(row[1]) / 1000)

        if n == 193:
            m193 += 1
        elif n == 195:
            m195 += 1

print('193*: ' + str(m193))
print('195*: ' + str(m195))
```

p/s: В фрагменте файла строка Linkoln имеет неверный формат

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое!